# Conditional sum in Numbers (iWork)

Tags: iwork

I would like to ask how to sum values in one column.
Let say I have two columns Date and Amount and need to sum Amount for those rows that have non empty Date.

I am using Numbers from Apple (iWork).
I could have been able to figure out a workaround. Creating an other column temp=ISBLANK(Date) and use SUMIF(temp, TRUE, Amount). But it seems to me pretty ugly. I want something like SUMIF(ISBLANK(Date), TRUE, Amount) which doesn't work.

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

Try `SUMIF ( 'DATE', "=" & " ", 'Amount')`

What this does is test that a Date value is not blank, using the = operator and a blank, as a concatenated string.  I don't know why the concatenated string form works but the direct form ( "= " ) doesn't,

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to sum rows WITH an empty cell (as opposed to the OP's non-empty cell), and this worked for me in Numbers 4.1 for Mac:

```
=SUMIF('DATE',"",'Amount')
```

That is, by making the condition simply an empty string, it summed only the rows that had empty strings in the `DATE` field.

Comment: I tried fussing with it a bit to give me the rows with non-empty cells (including using @jetset's answer), but made no progress.